# Wordpress custom SQL-Query, too heavy?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, inner-join

can anyone help me to optimize my query in wordpress?

**PHP code**

```
$serSlugSearchWord = seoUrl($post->post_title);
$serSlugSearchWord_obj = explode("-", $serSlugSearchWord);
foreach ($serSlugSearchWord_obj as $item )
{
    $queryStringKeyWords .= " if( INSTR(post_name, '$item')>0 ,1,0) +";
}

$queryStringKeyWords = preg_replace("/\+$/", "", $queryStringKeyWords);
$theQuery = "Select
$queryStringKeyWords 
as my_rate,
`wp_posts`.*  
from `wp_posts`
WHERE (`post_status` = 'publish' )
AND `post_type` = 'post'
order by my_rate desc limit 0, 10";
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->get_row($theQuery, 'ARRAY_N');
```

**a query looks like this (and work great)**

```
Select if( INSTR(post_name, 'serengeti')>0 ,1,0) + if( INSTR(post_name, 'adventure')>0 ,1,0) as my_rate, `wp_posts`.* from `wp_posts` 
WHERE (`post_status` = 'publish' ) 
AND `post_type` = 'post' 
order by my_rate desc limit 0, 10
```

**and now i want only posts from the category 1 and 5**

```
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships
ON wp_term_relationships.object_id = ID
AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = 1
OR wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = 5
```

**but when i add this lines to the code**

```
Select if( INSTR(post_name, 'serengeti')>0 ,1,0) + if( INSTR(post_name, 'adventure')>0 ,1,0) as my_rate, `wp_posts`.* from `wp_posts` 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships
ON wp_term_relationships.object_id = ID
AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = 1
OR wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = 5
WHERE (`post_status` = 'publish' ) 
AND `post_type` = 'post' 
order by my_rate desc limit 0, 10
```

it crashed my webspace (server). But why?

Btw.: This query is only for the admin.

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by "it crashed my webspace?" ... does the query consume too many resources? Did you try to `EXPLAIN` the query, to understand the execution plan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(updated) can you try this? The OR condition is placed in a bracket.

```
Select if( INSTR(post_name, 'serengeti')>0 ,1,0) + if( INSTR(post_name, 'adventure')>0 ,1,0) as my_rate, `wp_posts`.* from `wp_posts` 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships
ON wp_term_relationships.object_id = ID
WHERE (`post_status` = 'publish' ) 
AND `post_type` = 'post' 
AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id in (1,5)
order by my_rate desc limit 0, 10
```